# default layout (header, footer) with next-router

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I searched through similar questions, but couldn't finally understand how to achieve what I need. Sorry for duplicate or very noob question.

I'm trying to migrate from CRA to Next, so I start with routes.

In my App.js in CRA I have:

```
const DefaultLayout = ({withSlider, component: Component, ...rest}) => {  
    return (
     <Route {...rest} render={matchProps => (
       <Fragment>
         <Nav withSlider={withSlider}/>
         <Component {...matchProps} />
         <Footer />
       </Fragment>
   )} />
  )
};
```

So then I organize all the routes in app like this:

```
 <Router>
   <Switch>
     <DefaultLayout exact path="/" withSlider={true} component={MainPage} />
     <DefaultLayout exact path="/people" withSlider={false} component={People} />
     <DefaultLayout exact path="/news" withSlider={false} component={News} />
     <DefaultLayout exact path="/news/:uid" withSlider={false} component={Article} />
   </Switch>
  </Router>
```

So two questions regarding Next

1. How do I achive DefaultLayout with parameter withSlider sending to Components?
2. How do I send :uid parameter in URL to component (to get it later via match.params)?

p.s. I know about [next-routes](https://github.com/fridays/next-routes), but I thought this functionality is so common that somehow it has to be implemented in next-router itself

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that I found an answer to 2. 
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/parameterized-routing